# How do I get rid of type errors when pulling data from html objets in Typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, types, interface

I wanted to get some practice using Typescript, so I chose a small vanilla JS project and set out to convert it to a Typescript project. I basically copied all the code over to a new project and instead named my JS files with the .ts extension. I made sure that I had Typescript installed and that my VS Code had the Typescript Compiler. As I expected this gave me a massive list of errors in my .ts files because I didn't have types anywhere in my code. I attacked each error one by one and was able to figure out the issue with some googling, but now I'm stuck on the last error, and my google searches don't seem to be helping.

The error is coming up every time I try to access a piece of data from an event.target object using bracket notation:

```
  const borrowForm = document.getElementById("borrowBookForm")

  borrowForm.onsubmit = event => {
    event.preventDefault()
    const bookID = parseInt(event.target[0].value, 10)
    alert(library.borrow(bookID))
    event.target[0].value = ""
  }
```

Both instances of `event.target[0]` give me the following error:

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type '0' can't be used to index type 'EventTarget'.

Property '0' does not exist on type 'EventTarget'.
```

I tried fixing this by adding an interface for EventTarget with no success

I then tried to access the data I want by targeting it directly through the DOM like this:

```
  const borrowForm = document.getElementById("borrowBookForm")

  borrowForm.onsubmit = event => {
    event.preventDefault()
    const bookToBorrow = document.getElementById("bookToBorrow").value
    const bookID = parseInt(bookToBorrow, 10)
    alert(library.borrow(bookID))
    bookToBorrow.value = ""
  }
```

But in this case `.value` gives me this error:

```
Property 'value' does not exist on type 'HTMLElement'.
```

I tried fixing this by adding an interface for HTMLElement that looked like this:

```
export interface IHTMLElement {
  value: string
}
```

...but that didnt work either.

In both cases, I've hit a dead-end.

It is worth mentioning that these are superficial errors, and that my program performs as expected at runtime, but the purpose of this exercise was to learn more about how Typescript works by removing all the errors that it found with my JS code. I also wanted to achieve this with the `"noImplicitAny": true` setting turned on (perhaps this is where I went wrong?). Any guidance would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you start using selectors, the return type isn't known by the TypeScript compiler, so you have to cast it at times. Here's an example of what you can do to calm down the TypeScript Compiler

```
const element = document.getElementById('something');
const elementValue = (element as HTMLInputElement).value;
```

or

```
const element = document.getElementById('something') as HTMLInputElement;
const elementValue = element.value;
```

Explanation:

`document.getElementById` returns an `Element`. `Element.value` doesn't exist, so you get a TypeScript error.

So, by telling TypeScript that the element returned from your `document.getElementById` is of the type `HTMLInputElement`, you can then access `.value` without issue.

The same goes for `Event.target`, it returns an `EventTarget` so you have to cast it to the type of element you are wanting to work with

Same thing with form:

```
const form = document.getElementById('myform') as HTMLFormElement;
form.onsubmit = e => console.log(e);
```

I **would not** recommend creating wrapper interfaces to handle your problem like you did with the `IHTMLElement` interface. Just cast it. The next thing you'll run into is missing methods/properties and you'll eventually just end up with duplicate class of the one that already exists.

Or, another **would not** recommend, disable the `any` rule in your `tslint.json`

https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/no-any/

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target